# Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' writing to Excel

Tags: excel, vb.net, visual-studio-2015

I've got a simple test app to demonstrate, it must be environment in some way as the complied app works on other pc's but not mine ! The research i've done has suggested uninstalling VS2015 which I've done but still not working.

here's the code

```
Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Public Class Form1
  Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim xls As New Excel.Application
    Dim book As Excel.Workbook
    Dim sheet As Excel.Worksheet

    xls.Workbooks.Add()
    book = xls.ActiveWorkbook
    sheet = book.ActiveSheet

    sheet.Cells(1, 1) = "Some Text"
    sheet.Cells(1, 2) = "More Text"

    xls.Workbooks.Close()
    xls.Quit()

    releaseObject(sheet)
    releaseObject(book)
    releaseObject(xls)

    MsgBox("Worked", MsgBoxStyle.Information)

  End Sub
  Private Sub releaseObject(obj As Object)
    Try
      System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(obj)
      obj = Nothing
    Catch ex As Exception
      obj = Nothing
      MessageBox.Show("Exception Occured while releasing object " & ex.ToString())
    Finally
      GC.Collect()
    End Try
  End Sub
End Class
```

it falls over on the... sheet.Cells(1, 1) = "Some Text"

Now that i've uninstalled VS2015 I'm using the compiled app above to prove my machine (which is still failing) works once i find the right fix.

But I'm struggling to work out what to do next ? I really don't want to have to wipe my machine if I can avoid it.

Comment: Try `sheet.Cells(1, 1).Value = "Some Text"` as, unlike from VBA, it won't assume a default property for this Range (COM) object.

Comment: I tried add both .Text and .Value and same error, also doesn't explain why it works on other machines ?

Comment: Actually, I've removed my answer because I've tested your code and it is not necessary to be explicit about `.Value`. Your code works for me so I cannot advise further.

Comment: Thankyou for your time and effort Andy G

Comment: I would try/test with `book.Worksheets(0)` rather than `book.ActiveSheet`. Good luck.